# JVM and heap size in a pod on kubernetes

Tags: java, jvm

I have a container that has been allocated 10Gi of memory in kubernetes. Its running a spring boot java 17 application - all default parameters.

My understanding is that a certain portion of the requested memory for the container is given to the jvm heap. What i wanted to know is this fixed, does it increase if it needs more. And how much does it allocate?

i know i can set the following:

```
VM parameters -Xms and -Xmx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in Kubernetes when you allocate memory for a container, the JVM heap size is usually set as a portion of the allocated memory. The `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters in Java control the initial and maximum heap sizes, respectively.

Here's a breakdown of these parameters and how they relate to Kubernetes memory allocation:

```
-Xms (Initial Heap Size):
```

This parameter sets the initial size of the heap when the JVM starts.
It is the amount of memory that the JVM initially requests from the operating system for the heap.
In a Kubernetes environment, this can be set based on your application's expected minimum memory requirements.
For example, you might set `-Xms512m` to specify an initial heap size of 512 megabytes.

```
-Xmx (Maximum Heap Size):
```

This parameter sets the maximum size that the heap can grow to.
The JVM will not use more memory than specified by this parameter for the heap.
In Kubernetes, you might set this based on the allocated memory for your container.
For example, if your container is allocated 10Gi of memory, you might set -`Xmx8g` to leave some memory for non-heap usage and avoid excessive swapping.

It's important to note that the JVM doesn't dynamically increase the heap size beyond what is specified by the `-Xmx` parameter. If your application needs more heap space than allocated, it might encounter out-of-memory errors. Therefore, it's essential to monitor your application's memory usage and adjust the container memory allocation and JVM heap size accordingly.

In summary, set the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters based on your application's memory requirements and the allocated memory for the container in Kubernetes. Regularly monitor and adjust these settings as needed based on the actual memory usage patterns of your application.

Comment: Thanks. My other question would be if xmx is not set by me, what would the default behaviour be. Would JVM get a percentage of the 10G like 30%. Is there some setting which give a default

Comment: the JVM will use a default value based on the available physical memory on the machine where it's running. The default maximum heap size is often calculated as a fraction of the physical memory, but the specific algorithm can vary between different JVM implementations.

In a containerized environment like Kubernetes, the JVM might not be able to accurately determine the host machine's physical memory because it runs within a constrained environment. Therefore, the default behavior could lead to suboptimal heap sizes for your container.

Comment: To ensure that the JVM heap size is appropriately configured for your containerized Java application, it's recommended to explicitly set the `-Xmx ` parameter based on your application's memory requirements and the allocated memory for the container. This provides more predictable behavior and avoids potential issues with the JVM making assumptions about the host environment.